# merging maps, but some values are nil

Tags: clojure, hashmap

So I have two maps that can be anything and I want to merge them, but not include values that are nil.
Let's say I have:

```
(def x {:a "A" :c 5 :d "D"})
(def y {:a 1 :b 2 :c nil})
```

I want to end up with

```
{:a 1 :b 2 :c 5 :d "D"}
```

I get the wrong value for :c if I just merge like (merge x y), but {:c nil} is there. I do not have control over what two maps come in. Any help would be aappreciated

Comment: Also, if `x` was `{:a nil}` and `y` was `{:b 2}` would the desired result be `{:a nil :b 2}` or `{:b 2}`? There is a difference between filtering *all* nil values versus preventing `nil` values in later maps overriding values in earlier maps. The differences can be seen in the two answers already given.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [into](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/into) with the second argument being a [filter](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/filter)ing transducer results in a piece of code that is both fairly concise and readable:

```
(def x {:a "A" :c 5 :d "D"})
(def y {:a 1 :b 2 :c nil})

(into x (filter (comp some? val)) y)
;; => {:a 1, :c 5, :d "D", :b 2}
```

Only minor tweaks are required to have it remove nils from the *first* map too, if you need that:

```
(def x {:a "A" :c 5 :d "D" :e nil :f nil})
(def y {:a 1 :b 2 :c nil})

(into {} (comp cat (filter (comp some? val))) [x y])
;; => {:a 1, :c 5, :d "D", :b 2}
```

Comment: I'd probably use `val` instead of `second` here to make it clear that it is working with map entries but otherwise this is a really neat solution to the problem!

Comment: Instead of `(filter (comp some? val))`, a more literal encoding of the intent "remove nil values" could be `(remove (comp nil? val))`

Comment: Thanks, all! The solution was perfect!
(into {} (comp cat (remove (comp nil? val))) [x y])

Answer (score 5):

If you want to merge hash maps in a way that doesn't let `nil` values override non-`nil` values, you can use `merge-with`:

```clj
dev=> (def x {:a "A" :c 5 :d "D"})
#'dev/x
dev=> (def y {:a 1 :b 2 :c nil})
#'dev/y
dev=> (merge-with (fn [a b] (if (some? b) b a)) x y)
{:a 1, :c 5, :d "D", :b 2}
dev=>
```

`some?` returns `true` if its argument is any non-`nil` value.

Answer (score 1):

A bit similar to what already Sean Corfield answered, but a little bit shorter:

```
(merge-with #(or %1 %2) x y)
```

Example:

```
user=> (def x {:a "A" :c 5 :d "D"})
#'user/x
user=> (def y {:a 1 :b 2 :c nil})
#'user/y
user=> (merge-with #(or %1 %2) x y)
{:a "A", :c 5, :d "D", :b 2}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can easily remove map entries that contain a `nil` like so:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [schema.core :as s]
  ))

(defn remove-nil-vals
  [m]
  (into {}
        (for [[k v] m
              :when (not (nil? v))]
          [k v])))

(dotest
  (let [x              {:a "A" :c 5 :d "D"}
        y              {:a 1 :b 2 :c nil}
        all-maps       [x y]
        merged-no-nils (into {}
                             (for [m all-maps]
                               (remove-nil-vals m)))]

    (is= (remove-nil-vals x)  {:a "A" :c 5 :d "D"})
    (is= (remove-nil-vals y)  {:a 1 :b 2})
    (is= merged-no-nils       {:a 1 :c 5 :d "D" :b 2})

  ))
```

The above is based on [this template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template).